# Double entry to Türkiye with a single-entry eVisa

Tags: customs-and-immigration, turkey, multiple-entry, e-visas

I am an Indian Passport holder with a valid Schengen visa (thus qualifying me for a single-entry 30-day Türkiye eVisa). I have two stopovers in Istanbul; one in January and one in February. I want to use the opportunity to visit the city on both legs. The entry dates are just about 30 days apart; and well within the 180-day apparent timeframe for a single visa.

Would I be able to obtain two separate eVisas, one for each visit? Or is there some restriction on the time between trips/visa applications to the country for single-entry eVisa holders? As the legs are both just over 30 days apart, I fear that I won’t be able to hold two eVisas at the same time / would be ineligible to re-apply within that period.

There is a lot of contradictory information online, and Turkish authorities were not helpful in this case. The [eVisa website](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/) is very confusing:

> If the duration of 90-day-stay on your e-Visa expired within 180 days as of your first entry date, you can reapply for an e-Visa 180 days later starting from the first entry date. If you spent some part of the duration of 90-day-stay on a multiple entry e-Visa within 180 days as of your first entry date and the rest expired after 180 days elapsed as of the first entry date, it is possible to reapply for an e-Visa. Anyway, please keep in mind that you may stay in Türkiye up to 90 days in every 180 days starting from the first entry date.

Any help from someone who has been in a similar situation, or from anyone with better research, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It *sounds* like the sum total of your visits must not exceed 90 days within a 180 day period. If your visits are short stopovers then I think it should not be a problem. I have been in simultaneous posession of two Turkey e-visas  (a few years ago), both apparently valid, due to an error on the entry date (however the validity of the earlier granted one was not tested). But this is not a definitive answer in your particular case, hence a comment.

Comment: I think your best best is to call the local Turkish consulate to check. I would indeed agree that as long as you do not stay longer than 30 days per stay or 90 days per 180 it should be fine, but I can't find any hard evidence or reference to support that.

Comment: I am in same situation. Were you able to figure out. I get a single entry visa and i wanna stay in turkey both way of my trip for a day each. If i get 2 e visas one to stay for a day on march 20 and 1 for a day stay on Apr 4. Will that be OK?

Comment: @Johnnyjanko **Türkiye** is the official name of the country. **Turkish** is the language of Türkiye. [Turkey's name changed to Türkiye | United Nations in Türkiye](https://turkiye.un.org/en/184798-turkeys-name-changed-t%C3%BCrkiye) and [Turkish language of Türkiye](https://www.ktb.gov.tr/EN-117846/language.html)

Comment: The country has asked the English speaking part of the world to change the spelling of the name of the country to Türkiye, so that is the name in English these days.

Comment: @Willeke I'm not going to push it any further, but personally I think that as long as the English language Wikipedia can use the term "Turkey", we can do the same. At present, the version "Türkiye" looks too official in English, like saying Côte d'Ivoire instead of Ivory Coast. Yes, it's an official name, but this is not an official text. It should be practical more than official or anything else.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko In this case the OP chose to use Türkiye when writing the question. It should not be for others to automaticlly change it to something else (which is what happened here).

Comment: @MarkJohnson if it's the OP who used the term Türkiye, then of course, I accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based **solely** on the reading of the [eVisa Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/):

- **Option 1**: the second application should be granted since the expected arrival date of the second entry is less than 90 days after the first.
- **Option 2**: apply after you leave the first time.

These 2 options may fail if the computer program doesn't take this situation into account.

Since *The e-Visa application fee is only charged to an approved e-Visa*, a failed application intails no cost.

---

> [The duration of 90-day-stay on my e-Visa expired and I have come back to my country timely. How many days should be passed until I reapply?](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/the-duration-of-90-day-stay-on-my-e-visa-expired-and-i-have-come-back-to-my-country-timely-how-many-days-should-be-passed-until-i-reapply/)
> ...
> Anyway, please keep in mind that you may stay in Türkiye **up to 90 days in every 180 days starting from the first entry date**.

If the first stay is only 2 days and a second stay, 30 days later, also 2 days then that would be **4 days** (out of 90) within the 180 days starting from the first entry date.

This rule probably doesn't even apply in this case, since the OP will recieve a 1 month visa due to the existing Schengen Visa.

> [Visa Information For Foreigners / Republic of Türkiye Ministry of Foreign Affairs](https://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa)
> ...
> **India:**
> ...
> Ordinary, Special and Service passport holders with a valid Schengen members or USA, UK, Ireland visa or residence permit may get their single entry e-Visas valid for **one month** via the website [www.evisa.gov.tr](http://www.evisa.gov.tr), provided that they meet certain conditions.

So 2 visas, with entries around 1 month apart, should pose no problem.

---

**Sources**:

- [Visa Information For Foreigners - Republic of Türkiye Ministry of Foreign Affairs](https://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa)

  - Overview of general visa rules
  - Country list with basic entry requirements for that country
- [e-Visa - Frequently Asked Questions - Republic of Türkiye Ministry of Foreign Affairs](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/)

  - [Who is eligible for e-Visa?](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/who-is-eligible-for-e-visa/)

    - List of countries eligible
  - [Can I obtain a multiple-entry e-Visa?](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/can-i-obtain-a-multiple-entry-e-visa/)

    - List of countries eligible
  - [If my e-Visa application is denied, will my payment be refunded?](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/if-my-e-visa-application-is-denied-will-my-payment-be-refunded/)

    - The e-Visa application fee is only charged to an approved e-Visa.
  - [Can the citizens of all the countries eligible for e-Visa obtain a visa on arrival?](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/can-the-citizens-of-all-the-countries-eligible-for-e-visa-obtain-a-visa-on-arrival/)

    - List of countries **not eligible** for visa on arrival

      - India
  - [The duration of 90-day-stay on my e-Visa expired and I have come back to my country timely. How many days should be passed until I reapply?](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/the-duration-of-90-day-stay-on-my-e-visa-expired-and-i-have-come-back-to-my-country-timely-how-many-days-should-be-passed-until-i-reapply/)

Answer (score -2):

You shall apply for a multiple-entry visa, just to stay on the legal side of the matter, otherwise your entry might be denied or you might be deported with an annotation of illegal entry, unless you wish to apply for 2 separate visas, what is definitely an option!

Comment: Indian citizens are not eligible for multiple-entry eVisas: [Can I obtain a multiple-entry e-Visa?](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/can-i-obtain-a-multiple-entry-e-visa/)